# How do I create a WP website login portal for customers (contacts or accounts) in Salesforce's database?

Tags: api, connected-apps, login, wordpress

The idea is to let customers login in a private area on our WordPress website to provide some specific content for them like downloads, tutorials, etc. Our customers database is stored in Salesforce and continuously updated. I am looking for options to connect the WordPress login area with Salesforce data, but after a few hours of  research I feel like I could use some extra guidance.

At the moment we do not have any 'Authenticated Website User Licenses' or any other type of login area for our customers. In other words, our customers do not have any login credentials yet, so they will need to be able to create them through the portal or Salesforce. I have some basic coding experience but building something like this from scratch would not be ideal for time constraints.

Both platforms are very popular so I though I would find some sort of pre-made connector. I came across Auth0 but it looks like this could only work for users who already have a login for the Salesforce environment, not just contacts/accounts.

Any suggestions on which path to follow to complete this project is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@AFiore
In the case of auth0, you can use it to hold your users directory. Then you can configure salesforce to do SSO with Auth0 (AKA your users will use their auth0 credentials to access salesforce) and the same with wordpress.

Check this doc about how to configure salesforce to use auth0 as the identity provider https://auth0.com/docs/integrations/salesforce

Comment: Thanks for your input Germàn. Looks like I might need Salesforce communities as well and then connect it to Auth0.